# Bootstrap 3 Fluid Grid Issues

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

having trouble with laying out a fluid column layout in bootstrap 3.

the structure of the HTML elements looks like this:

```
div.container-fluid
  div.row.upperrow
  div.row.contentrow
    div.col-lg-3
    div.col-lg-1
    div.col-lg-5
    div.col-lg-3
```

even the first 3 divs, which only add up to 9/12 of the 12-column layout, are much wider than the page.  the div.col-lg-5 easily takes up 70% of the row (not 5/12).  the div.col-lg-3 is pushed under the first 3 divs as they are too wide.

what could be the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated at http://getbootstrap.com/css/:

Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows.

Your layout has a row as child from another row. Put another col-12 in between or remove one row.

Comment: so container-fluid is a row?  otherwise i don't understand the "row as child from another row" comment.  neither upperrow nor contentrow are children of each other.

Comment: No, sorry, my mistake. I thought you had contentrow within upperrow. Rows must be within containers (fluid is ok), columns must be within rows, and content goes in columns. Have you tried with only container, not container-fluid? What happens then?

Comment: it didn't work with the fixed container either.  then i randomly changed the column widths around (still totalling 12) and it started working correctly.  no idea what the problem was, the old columns added up to 12 as well yet overflowed the row.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pjBzY/49/). Here is how it works.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <p class="text-center">Here is a row</p>
    </div><br/>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3 col">Col 3</div>
        <div class="col-2 col-sm-1 col-lg-2 col">Col 2</div>
        <div class="col-4 col-sm-5 col-lg-4 col">Col 4</div>
        <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3 col">Col 3</div>
    </div>
</diV>
```